# AngularJs 1.6 passing Service function to a generic Model loses context

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, model, prototypal-inheritance

in my project I have a few models that basically do the same things, so I am trying to refactor with a generic "BaseModel" stored in a service.

In my old models, I injected a 'ValidatorService' and called certain functions such as 'ValidatorService.isValidStreetNumber(streetNumber)'. This was fine, because the Model service could directly call the ValidatorService (Singleton) function.

Notice in the following that I am passing the validation/normalization functions anonymously with prototypal inheritance. (typeValidator, contentValidator, contentNormalizer)

Now my generic class looks like this (Coffeescript):

```
app = angular.module 'app'

BaseModel = ()->
    Model = (data, defaultData, isRequired, errorMessage, \
        typeValidator, contentValidator, contentNormalizer)->   
        this.defaultData        = defaultData
        this.isRequired         = isRequired
        this.errorMessage       = errorMessage
        this.typeValidator      = typeValidator
        this.contentValidator   = contentValidator
        this.contentNormalizer  = contentNormalizer

        this.data               = this.initialValue(data)
        this.isValid            = this.contentValidator(this.data)
        return

    Model.prototype.initialValue = (value)->
        if not this.typeValidator(value)
            return this.defaultData     
        return value

    Model.prototype.updateValidity = ()->
        this.isValid = this.isValidModel()
        return

    Model.prototype.isValidModel = ()->
        if not this.typeValidator(this.data)
            return false

        emptyOptional = not this.isRequired and
                        angular.equals(this.data, this.defaultData)

        return emptyOptional or this.contentValidator(this.data)

    Model.inherit = (data, defaultData, isRequired, errorMessage, typeValidator, contentValidator, contentNormalizer)->
        return Object.create(new Model(data, defaultData, isRequired, errorMessage, typeValidator, contentValidator, contentNormalizer))

return Model

BaseModel
    .$inject = []

app
    .service 'BaseModel', BaseModel
```

The initialization of a simple inheriting class looks like this:

```
Street = (streetName)-> 
    defaultData         =  ""
    isRequired          = true
    errorMessage        = ValidatorService.errorMessageStreet()
    typeValidator       = ValidatorService.isValidString
    contentValidator    = ValidatorService.isValidStreet

    return BaseModel.inherit(streetName, defaultData, isRequired, \
                            errorMessage, typeValidator, contentValidator)
```

This works fine if the passed functions are isolated and don't reference anything else. However, since my "ValidationService" functions call other functions with "this.", the anonymized functions throw errors.

Example:

```
this.isValidName = (string)->
    regexp = this.internationalLettersNumbers("{1,60}")
    return this.isRegexpMatch(string, regexp)
```

The only thing I can think of is to make the validation functions not reference any other functions or libraries. This is not a solution for me, however, as I also reference other services like a 'LocaleService'. Basically, I am stuck.

Is there a good way around this problem? Perhaps even an "angular" way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this problem can be avoided with the following, even though I haven't be able to reproduce the problem completely in my unit tests... The idea is that you don't use 'this', but instead explicitly reference the model object being returned by the service:

```
validatorService.prototype.isValidName = (string)->
    regexp = validatorService.prototype.internationalLettersNumbers("{1,60}")
    return validatorService.prototype.isRegexpMatch(string, regexp)
```